# Please Explain this Convert.ToInt64 InputStringFormat Exception

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

Can someone tell me why:

```
var nl = Convert.ToInt64("17029268.1650117");
```

fails, and instead you have to do this:

```
var nl = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble("17029268.1650117"));
```

Because it seems so stupid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably also use long.Parse(str)

A long is a whole number, so you can't have decimals dude. 
(tried to tell you on twitter :) )

Answer (score 7):

The [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zahhahw.aspx) says:

> FormatException:
>
> value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (zero through nine).

and a `.` is not in **`a sequence of digits`**.